# create view and alter in all tables

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, dynamic-sql

I am attempting to create a logic within the procedure using cursors to create database views for all the tables and create a new column called `HISTORY_DATE` for all tables in the schema. I need help building the logic below.

```
create or replace PROCEDURE ALTER_TABLES(
  RC OUT INT
  ,MSG OUT VARCHAR)
AS
BEGIN

DECLARE

CURSOR TBL_CUR IS
  SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM USER_TABLES;
TBL_REC TBL_CUR%ROWTYPE;  
SQL_STMT  VARCHAR(2000);

BEGIN
  OPEN TBL_CUR;
    LOOP
      FETCH TBL_CUR INTO TBL_REC;
      EXIT WHEN TBL_CUR%NOTFOUND;

      PRINT_DETAILS(TBL_REC.TABLE_NAME);            


      SQL_STMT:= 'ALTER TABLE '
         || TBL_REC.TABLE_NAME
         || ' ADD HISTORY_DATE DATE'
         || ' AND'
         || ' CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW all_tbl AS'
         || ' SELECT *'
         || ' FROM USER_TABLES'
         ;

      PRINT_DETAILS(SQL_STMT);
      EXECUTE IMMEDIATE SQL_STMT;


    END LOOP;
  CLOSE TBL_CUR;

  rollback;

END;

END;
```

Comment: You need to do these as separate statements.

Answer (score 0):

You only want to create the view once; and you cannot do two things at once as Gordon Linoff mentioned.  So take the view creation outside of the loop; something like this (untested):

```
create or replace PROCEDURE ALTER_TABLES(RC OUT INT
                                    ,MSG OUT VARCHAR)
AS
BEGIN

DECLARE

CURSOR TBL_CUR IS
SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM USER_TABLES;
TBL_REC TBL_CUR%ROWTYPE;  
SQL_STMT  VARCHAR(2000);

BEGIN
          SQL_STMT  := 'CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW all_tbl AS'
                 || ' SELECT *'
                 || ' FROM USER_TABLES';
          PRINT_DETAILS(SQL_STMT);
          EXECUTE IMMEDIATE SQL_STMT;

          OPEN TBL_CUR;
              LOOP
                FETCH TBL_CUR INTO TBL_REC;
                EXIT WHEN TBL_CUR%NOTFOUND;

                PRINT_DETAILS(TBL_REC.TABLE_NAME);            


                 SQL_STMT:= 'ALTER TABLE '
                 || TBL_REC.TABLE_NAME
                 || ' ADD (HISTORY_DATE DATE)'
                 ;

                  PRINT_DETAILS(SQL_STMT);
                  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE SQL_STMT;


              END LOOP;
          CLOSE TBL_CUR;

--rollback;

END;
```

Now, I don't see a need to create a view `all_tbl` as all it is, is a copy of the view `USER_TABLES` -- so just use `USER_TABLES`  -- but I left it's creation there so if you need only certain columns from `USER_TABLES` or certain rows, you know where to place that.

Comment: I need to create view for all tables, which is why I put it in loops. Also, I wanted to make this dynamic. What kind of input should I seek from the user?

Comment: So, you want one view created for each table in user_tables?  What kind of input from the user depends on ... what the user might need??  One idea is a view could just return no more than 10 rows of a table, regardless of how many rows.  Almost anything else would be table-specific and would be difficult to code.